# Name That ...Name? 13

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> No matter where I am, you'll always be mine
>
> An association of a sport makes me a food to dine
>
> I died in film in the 2000s not to early
>
> America murders me when I channel the otherworldly
>
> Speaking of that, I am a pet of many names
>
> A Dubai tower and rapper made my body sold, it claims

Name the Name

Comment: The Burj Khalifa and Wiz Khalifa can be found for the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer

> Mia Khalifa

---

```
No matter where I am, you'll always be mine
```

> Mia is "mine" in Spanish.

```
An association of a sport makes me a food to dine
```

> She co-hosted some talks for NBA, giving her "food to dine".

```
I died in film in the 2000s not to early
```

> In 2017, Mia Sutton dies in "Death Note" film. Probably, hundreds of Mia died in films. I just chose one. Also, this might refer to the threats she received for "performing" with a hijab.

```
America murders me when I channel the otherworldly
```

> There were rumours about her death in a car accident. She also received many threats for "performing" with a hijab.

```
Speaking of that, I am a pet of many names
```

> Mia Callista and Mia Khalifia are some of her "other names". "Pet" might refer to her "adult industry job" and the names she'd been called.

```
A Dubai tower and rapper made my body sold, it claims
```

> Burj Khalifa Tower in Dubai and Wiz Khalifa (rapper).

---

I feel dirty for answering this, but I'm convinced this one is the answer.
Particularly, the first and the last line gave it away.

Comment: If this is the answer... hold on, Rot13(vfa'g Zvn Xunyvsn n... jryy... cbeabtencul npgerff? Vfa'g Zvn Xunyvsn n... jryy... cbeabtencul npgerff? Qba'g nfx zr ubj V xabj...) ;)

Comment: Yeah, rot13(fur vf)

Comment: Correct partially, the first name is correct. The lines refer to different people with the first name. I'll give you it though since you got the name, good job.